# Laravel + Vue return data with more than one relation

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, model-view-controller

I have a model called Exercise, that belongs to Topic, and a Topic belongs to a Subject.

With

```
Exercise::with('topic')->get()
```

I can access properties from the current topic of the exercise inside Vue. What can I do to return also the data from the subject that the topic that my exercise belongs to?

If I was able to use just blade template, I would just call:

```
{{$exercise->topic->subject->name}}
```

But the thing is that I'm passing everything as a json to work with the data in a datatable with vue.

One solution is to also pass `Subject::all` to my view, and use the subject_id inside the exercise>topic with vue:

```
@{{subjects[exercise.topic.subject_id].name}}
```

I'm looking for a better and cleaner solution than that. Is there a Laravel method, like multiple with's with multiple relations? Something like:

```
Exercise::with('topic')->and('topic')->with('subject')->get()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal - seems like you're in need of a more robust API solution.

Comment: @Trent I'm reading it... Do you really think that it'll be necessary?

Comment: That's up to you to decide, a serializer like fractal will allow you to define very light serializsed objects (just exercise for example), then use ->includes to get all the other data you want only when you need it. Note: fractal will add some processing overhead

Comment: @Trent But I'll need to create transformers for every complex data structure?

Comment: @Trent Isn't there a laravel based solution? Because I'm in a hurry with that project so I don't want to create more and more layers of data processing... But I also don't want to do ugly solutions as the one that I've pointed out in the post!

Comment: Can't really have your cake and eat it. Either you keep abusing the controller and sending more and more crap and potentially repeat yourself elsewhere when you need to access the Exercise model and with includes, or you spend the extra day up front learning fractal and build it properly. If the project is throw away, then just build up a collection with the data you need, then pass that into the view context

Comment: @Thank you Trent, but the solution from Inzamam is clean and faster to implement. Anyway I didn't know about fractal... it's good to know about that... Maybe I'll use it in future! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data with the relation of topic belongs to subject so,

**Try this**:

```
Exercise::with('topic.subject')->get();
```

I hope it would be helpful.